# Add End Time to video in revealjs Quarto

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I would like to share a video in a `revealjs` presentation. We could use a [Start Time](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/videos.html) with the video like this:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

{{< video https://www.youtube.com/embed/wo9vZccmqwc
    title="What is the CERN?"
    start="116"
    aspect-ratio="21x9">}}
```

Output:

[image]

Which starts at the given time. Adding `end = "125"` for example doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add an end time to the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add it to the URL directly. Add `?start=[starttime]&end=[endtime]` to your URL:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

{{< video https://www.youtube.com/embed/wo9vZccmqwc?start=116&end=119
    title="What is the CERN?"
    aspect-ratio="21x9">}}
```